# Do any undergraduate theory textbooks explain Gregorian chant notation?

Tags: notation, learning-resources, chant

When it comes to common-practice notation, basically every college theory textbook explains all of the basics. But I don't know of any undergraduate theory textbook that includes a discussion of chant notation; are there any? And if so, what are they?

(I know this question is dangerously close to "requesting external resources," which is off-topic, but I think it's sufficiently separate, since I'm seeking a question with a clearly defined answer that does not require a link to said external resource.)

Comment: What sort of chant? I guess you mean Gregorian, not Anglican, which is usually written in conventional staff notation for the 4-part harmony - the only thing that needs any explanation is the "pointing" in the text showing how the words fit to the music, but that is almost self-evident to anyone who knows what a bar line is for!

Comment: @alephzero Yes, I meant Gregorian chant; silly omission on my part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fairly comprehensive tutorial (arranged in 45 "lessons" - don't be put off by the fact that at the start it also summarizes conventional staff notation) is 
https://media.musicasacra.com/books/basicgregorianchant_1960.pdf.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this tutorial only covers later (and modern) Gregorian notation, with square notes and a four line staff.  The original notation, in Gregory's time and up until about the thirteenth century, was unlined neumes.